# You are using ZeRO-Offload with a client provided optimizer (<class 'torch.optim.adamw.AdamW'>) which in most cases will yield poor performance

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, deepspeed

I am using Pytorch Lightning's Deepspeed strategy and I am trying to train a model and I receive this error.  What are different ways of fixing this with pros/cons?

```
deepspeed.runtime.zero.utils.ZeRORuntimeException: You are using ZeRO-Offload with a client provided optimizer (<class 'torch.optim.adamw.AdamW'>) which in most cases will yield poor performance. Please either use deepspeed.ops.adam.DeepSpeedCPUAdam or set an optimizer in your ds-config (https://www.deepspeed.ai/docs/config-json/#optimizer-parameters). If you really want to use a custom optimizer w. ZeRO-Offload and understand the performance impacts you can also set <"zero_force_ds_cpu_optimizer": false> in your configuration file.
```